# ¿Como llenar select con datos que provienen de un API?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Estoy trabajando con vue js, recibo los dato y los imprimo en consola, pero no logro llenar el select con los datos que obtengo, estoy intentando esto, me sale este error [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.created is not a function" y el select no se llena.

```
<template>
<v-row align="center">
<v-col cols="12">
    <v-select :items="archivo" :menu-props="{ top: true, offsetY: true }" label="Tipos de Archivos"> 
 </v-select>
 </v-col>
 </v-row>
 </template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import vSelect from 'vue-select'
export default {
components: {
    vSelect
},
data: () => {
    return {
        archivos: [],
        archivo: {
            Id_TipoArchivo: '',
            Archivo: '',
        },

    }
},
mounted() {
    this.created()
},
created() {
    axios.get('http://contago.dynns.com/api/AppWeb/consultaArchivoUsuario?usuario=')
        .then(res => {
            this.data = res.data;
            console.log(this.data);
        })
      },

     }
      </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ten en cuenta:

- Puedes quedarte solo con `created()`, este es un método reservado de Vue y no lo puedes invocar desde otro sitio por eso te sale error. El hook `created()` forma parte del [ciclo de vida de una instancia de Vue](https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Hooks-del-Ciclo-de-vida-de-la-Instancia).
- El attr `items`(este debe ser un arreglo) de tu select no se llena porque no estás guardando los datos que recibes de tu API en tu dato **`archivo`**.

```
created() {
  axios.get('http://contago.dynns.com/api/AppWeb/consultaArchivoUsuario?usuario=')
    .then(res => {
      // si res.data es un arreglo entonces podrías hacer esto
      this.archivo = res.data ;
    })
}
```

Comment: Hice el cambio, pero no me funciona, de hecho, al hacer ese cambio me muestra un arreglo de objetos

Comment: vale, ya que tu arreglo es de objetos, puedes seleccionar un attr para que se visualice, en tu select deberás colocar como atributo item-text="name" (este en el caso que quieras visualizar el atributo name de tu objeto dentro del arreglo), así tbm puede usar item-value="id" (en el caso que tengas id en tus objetos) como identificador de cada option de tu select.

Comment: Aquí te dejo la info de las [propiedades de v-select](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props)

Comment: Gracias me ha funcionado

Comment: Genial @DanielJiménez 